# How to modify Podfile in an Expo-Managed React Native project

Tags: react-native, expo, branch.io, podfile

I have implemented an app that uses `react-native-branch` and `@config-plugins/react-native-branch` with the expo-managed workflow but upon building with EAS in iOS (Expo Application Services), its throwing this error:

```
The Swift pod `ExpoAdapterBranch` depends upon `react-native-branch`, which does not define modules.
To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries),
you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
```

Is there a way to do this in expo-managed workflow?

Other details of our project:

- Expo SDK: v44
- react-native-branch: v5.0.0
- @config-plugins/react-native-branch: v1.0.2

Comment: Have you set `use_modular_headers` globally in your Podfile?

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no Podfile in our project as it is using the managed workflow and I can't afford to use the bare workflow.

Answer (score -1):

I finally get it to build in iOS without errors by updating my react-native-branch version from 5.0.0 to 5.4.0 without any other changes to the plugin. However, expo is now giving off a warning saying that

```
Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:
 - react-native-branch - expected version: 5.0.0 - actual version installed: 5.4.0
```

If anyone has a better solution to this, I would gladly hear it. Thanks!