# Enabling use_modular_header! in an expo managed project

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, expo

I am building an app in React Native using Expo that requires Firebase usage. When I try to compile an iOS build of the app, I get the following error.

> The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

I have looked over a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72125921/how-to-modify-podfile-in-an-expo-managed-react-native-project), but the author simply updated their packages, which I have already done. Looking over the [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#modifying-the-ios-podfile) for podfiles doesn't yield much better results, as it does not allow for free modification of the podfile. I have hit a wall with this issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you use Expo Go or do you compile your custom Expo Go app to pre-embed `react-native-firebase` ?

Comment: @ShyPenguin I am using Expo Go and the official Firebase SDK so that I do not have to eject to install the react-native-firebase SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This was reported as a bug against expo-cli and has a [resolution here](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1358).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in following way -

**Expo version 47 -**

In Build Properties (for native) we do not have `module_version` option to set in `app.json`. But we have `useFrameworks` so I used that.
Complete `app.json` configuration below -

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "--- App",
    ...
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.example.app",
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

However in **Expo version 48+** there is `module_version` so can be used in same way

Answer (score -5):

The solution was that I accidently used the wrong version of firebase! Grrrr. A simple uninstall of react-native-firebase and reinstallation of the official firebase module resolved the issue.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? What was the wrong version of firebase that you were using? What is the exact name and version of the "official firebase module" you installed?

Comment: Please could you specify things, this is not helpful 

Comment: The answer doesn't relate to the question.